# Selector to grab all <tr>s after a given row in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to take information from a `<tr>` and prefill it in all `<tr>`s below that `<tr>`.  I know I can grab the `<tr>` I want and put it in a variable, but is there a good selector for grabbing only the `<tr>`s below that row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(yourtr).nextAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be filtered for tr's?

```
$(yourtr).nextAll()
```

[An example.](http://jsbin.com/afodi), [the source](http://jsbin.com/afodi/edit).

Comment: Don't think anything can validly coexist with a tr at the sibling level other than other tr.  Might be some wackiness I never use that makes it possible, though.